# Line break in lightning-formatted-text

Tags: lightning-web-components

As per the SFDC documentations below, it should allow the new line chars (\r\n) but no luck, any idea: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-text/example

```
<lightning-formatted-text value="Email \n  salesforce.com and info.salesforce.com" ></lightning-formatted-text>
```

output:
Email \n  salesforce.com and info.salesforce.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add the field in your js like

```
textValue = "Email \n salesforce.com and info.salesforce.com";
```

then in the template :

```
<lightning-formatted-text value={textValue} linkify ></lightning-formatted-text>
```